# McAfee Blocked Incoming Anonymous Proxy

Tags: security

McAfee blocked an incoming connection from an anonymous proxy 37.130.227.133, does anyone know if my PC is now at risk somehow? I was under the impression that this shouldnt happen. Anyone have any input what this means? This happened after I was browsing sensitive information with javascript enabled on the 18th. Also my broswer froze and was displaying strange characters on some Tor sites following this. Anywhere I should look for malicious script on my PC? Im tech illiterate, any info would help. Thanks.

Comment: McAfee also stated that this was last attempted by "tor.exe"

Answer (score 1):

37.130.227.133 seems to be a Tor Node, I'm unsure if McAfee flagged that IP as a spammer IP address or if it was a treat.  Try switching your identity, you may find that at the Left-hand top Connor where the onion is.  Click "New identity"